# Sort array of object for some keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have one array of object like.

```
[{
  id: 1,
  age: 23
}, {
  id: 1,
  age: 25
}, {
  id: 2,
  age: 230
}, {
  id: 2,
  age: 255
}, {
  id: 3,
  age: 232
}, {
  id: 1,
  age: 215
}]
```

I need to get the final array by sorting with hightest age for each id. so final array will be.

```
[{
    id: 1,
    age: 215
  }, {
    id: 2,
    age: 255
  }, {
    id: 3,
    age: 232
  }]
```

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this problem yourself?

Comment: This doesn't seem sorting.

Comment: In what way is your desired output example sorted? And why do you have duplicate IDs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects

Comment: its just sample data. i just simplified it that for same id we can have different age values.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a hash in which you store the object with the maximum age for each id. Then sort its keys numerically and get the values in that order.

```
var hash = array.reduce(function(hash, obj) {
  if(!hash[obj.id]) hash[obj.id] = obj;
  else if(hash[obj.id].age < obj.age) hash[obj.id] = obj;
  return hash;
}, Object.create(null));
Object.keys(hash).sort(function(a,b) {
  return a - b;
}).map(function(id) {
  return hash[id];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a single liner here

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  age: 23,
}, {
  id: 1,
  age: 25,
}, {
  id: 2,
  age: 230,
}, {
  id: 2,
  age: 255,
}, {
  id: 3,
  age: 232,
}, {
  id: 1,
  age: 215,
}],
lut = {},
res = arr.sort((a,b) => b.age - a.age).filter(o => lut[o.id] ? false : lut[o.id] = true).sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use `filter` with `indexOf` to [remove duplicate elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array). In the case when array elements are objects, you can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to search for the index of a element by some given property values.

```js
let result = [{
  id: 1,
  age: 23,
}, {
  id: 1,
  age: 25,
}, {
  id: 2,
  age: 230,
}, {
  id: 2,
  age: 255,
}, {
  id: 3,
  age: 232,
}, {
  id: 1,
  age: 215,
}].sort((a,b) => b.age - a.age)
.filter((row,pos,self) => self.findIndex(item => item.id === row.id) === pos)
.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id);

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Also, you need to pay attention to its browser support.

Answer (score 0):

or this way to avoid using lodash's    uniq() method:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return b.id > a.id;
}).reverse();
var max = arr.length;
var i = 0;
while(i < max - 1){
  if (arr[i].id === arr[i+1].id) arr.splice(i+1,1);
  else i++
  max = arr.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do sorting this way Using vanillaJS.

```
function sortByAgeDesc(a,b) {return a.age > b.age ? -1 : a.age === b.age ? 0 : 1;}


output = input.sort(sortByAgeDesc);
```

Now the question is you want only distinct ids.